# Use several PC to generate vanity addresses

Tags: address, vanitygen

I have seven PC and I want to generate a unique Bitcoin address. On one PC the speed to generate addresses is low. 
How can I use `vanitygen.exe` on all of my computers to increase the speed of generating the intended vanity address?

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can simply run the software on all 7 machines and it will have the same expected completion time.

You will have the same mathematical probability of finding an address that matches what you're looking for in both cases.